How to get a contour polygon from multiple polyline?
The graph is made by multiple polylines. I would like to get a contour polygon and export it to the format of kml.
This is the origin graph:

After using lines to polygon:

What I expected:


There seems to be no way to make that collection of lines into the polygon you want, except may be by taking a convex hull of the points that make it up.

I tried convex hull,but it still failed. Actually it is a graph with two circular sectors and two trapezoids which are all made by polyline, thus it is not a convex hull graph.

Try the polygonize tool, then a dissolve.  It seems the lines to polygon tool has  always had odd results.

Extract vertices, than apply convex hull does not work? Maybe you can share a sample of your data for testing?


Remove 3 internal points from the points layer; 2) On the points layer, run the geo-tool - Concave hull; 3) Save the result: Export->Save objects as...*.kml.


It did succeed. In conclusion, extract multiple polyline to vertice points, and remove or add points that fit to the concave hull contour. Run the concave hull tool and tuning threshold parameter to make the polygon fit the contour. Finally, export it and save the feature as *.kml.
